# Change file icon for a specific file extension ion vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed `Material Icon Theme` and I want to change only the HTML file icon to an icon from Seti icon for VSCode. But after scouting through the internet, I can't find any working solution. Does anyone have someway to make it work?

Comment: there is one (1) File Icon Theme active in VSC. Create/Copy your own and merge the images of both Themes, or copy the Seti HTML icon to the Material icon extension, rename the file as needed, need to do this after each update of Material